# Unable to perform join using mongoose and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am used to using sql and not really getting this .populate or $lookup alternative using mongodb. I basically want to do this

```
SELECT firstName, lastName FROM customers c INNER JOIN invoices i ON i.customerId = c._id
```

When I find an invoice I want to get the customer details from their ID.

I tried doing using $lookup but get back an empty array.

```
  const test = await Invoice.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "customers",
        localField: "customerId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userinfo",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        firstName: 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log(test);
```

With populate I think I need a 'ref' but not sure where to put that in my schemas

Customer schema

```
const customerSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

Invoice schema

```
const invoiceSchema = new Schema({
  invoiceDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  customerId: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  invoiceNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: You aggregate from the `Invoice` collection right? So you need use lookup form customer collection. But you code says  `from: "invoices",`. But your sql says your need to aggregate from customer collection to invoice collection

Comment: @varman, ah. I have modified my question to what I hope is fixed. But I just get object ID's back instead of the customer first name. I also get back as many records as I have instead of just the one matching customer's details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your `invoiceSchema`, add `ref` to the `customerId` field, so it point to `CUSTOMERS` collection. You can do it like this:

```
customerId: {
  type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'CUSTOMERS'
  required: true,
},
```

Now you can just use `populate` of the `customerId` field when performing a query. You can do it like this:

```
Invoice.find({_id: invoice_id }).populate('customerId');
```

Now when you get result back, the `customerId` field will have customer information populated.

Comment: Thanks for this. Should the ref not be added to the Customer Schema though as that is where the customerId field is?

Comment: No. You will store that in `Invoice` Schema, and you will put the customer's `_id` in the `customerId` field of the `Invoice` Schema. And then, when performing a query, `Mongoose` will go to `Customers` collection and fetch customer with that `_id`, and those data will be putted in `customerId` field. That is what `populate` does.

Comment: Sorry, was getting muddled up with the names there! It works great, thanks so much